# How to refer to a new package created that is used for my flexdashboard?

Tags: r, deployment, package, build-tools, rsconnect

I have created a new package/library with Package  RBuild. The functions I have stored within this package are called into a flexdashboard RMarkdown. Now, the dashboard is deployed on rsconnect . Yet, I cannot deploy it since the library isn't recognized.

How to refer to the package/library into the package itself so that I won't have issues with deployment?

Comment: I think if you upload the package to github as a public repository and then install the package from there on your local machine, `rsconnect` will fetch it from github. At least that's how it works with shinyapps.io.

Comment: @Till this is a bitbucket repo that is within the company only. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: Check out the [posit connect docs](https://docs.posit.co/connect/admin/r/package-management/#private-r-packages), seems like bitbucket works too.

Comment: @Till - have tried to do something but it did not work. so, the I believe is how to set up the # A sample .Rprofile file with two different package repositories.
local({
  r <- getOption("repos")
  r["CRAN"] <- "https://cran.rstudio.com/"
  r["mycompany"] <- "http://rpackages.mycompany.com/"
  options(repos = r)
}) - specifically r["mycompany"] . it is on https://bitbucket.astrazeneca.net/scm/ecos/flexmetrics.git . is this the right one?